# Resizing Redshift cluster from dc1.8xlarge to ds2.8xlarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We currently have a Redshift cluster with dc1.8xlarge (Older generation Compute) type nodes and we would like to migrate it to ds2.8xlarge (New generation Storage) type nodes.

Should this be as easy as just resizing the cluster by choosing desired new node type or is there anything that I should take care of/be aware of besides the fact that cluster will be in read only mode or might not be available while the resize in progress ?

PS: I've already read most of the Redshift documentation available on this subject, so really looking for personal experiences here.

Comment: Yes, its as easy as that, do expect some downtime and some "warm up" time.

Comment: I would recommend taking a snapshot before resizing. This is not due to a risk of losing data. Rather, snapshots are tied to a particular a particular cluster size. When the snapshot is restored, it needs to go back to the same number and size of nodes. If you want to "undo" the resize, you can restore the snapshot rather than resizing again.